# Expo React Native - Emulator Debug menu shortcut suddenly stopped working on Windows

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo, android-virtual-device

I am developing React Native App using Expo (not ejected) and Android Studio official AVD.

I am on Windows.

There is shortcut `CTRL-M` what opens Expo's (React Native's ??) debug menu for app inside emulator.

It was working for many days but today it suddenly stopped working...

ADB command still works...

Any ideas what should be bad? Expo or AVD problem?

Comment: Can you uninstall expo on emulator and run expo start?

Comment: I already did. I also cleaned cache... No change...

Comment: Did you restart your dev machine\pc?

Comment: yes :D I did :D

Comment: Can you reset emulator?

Comment: Dude... I did everything :D Clean Emulator installation, Reinstalled Android Studio, Restarted PC, Reinstalled Expo

Comment: Can you try open menu through emulator menu button  side bar?

Comment: Emulator do not have option to open React's dev menu. Just normal Emulator's menu

Comment: Are you working in dev mode?

Comment: Yes sure :D How I said it was working fine last few days

Comment: And adb shell input keyevent 82 works?

Comment: Press 3 dots on emulator extended controls.
Go to Settings in there.
Set "Send keyboard shortcuts to : Emulator controls (default).

Comment: I have this... Yes...

Comment: And double tap R is working?

Comment: Nothing........

Comment: And can you input some text in ui?

Comment: yes I can......

Comment: Try to reinstall avd tools

Answer (score 2):

I tried every answer here and nothing worked, what ended up working for me was

- Reaload the app by double-pressing the "r" key
- While app is reloading (before it is fully loaded), press ctrl+m

I'm guessing - like another answer suggested - that React Navigation may be interfering with the shortcut in some way, as this bug only showed up after some significant navigation restructuring in the app I'm working on. Though their suggested fix didn't work for me, it seems that pressing the shortcut during the loading screen before the app is mounted gets around whatever the issue is, as React Navigation (or whatever else might be blocking it) isn't loaded and so can't interfere.

Hopefully that helps somebody in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation when switched from building and running project by `react-native run-android` command to `expo start`.

After effortless attempts to make <kbd>Ctrl+m</kbd> work, I found a solution by looking for the *Expo* application hosted during the project build into the simulator.

**Steps are:**
 1. Locate and open the *Expo* application inside the `Android` simulator.

[image]

2. Find your application from the listed apps and hit to open.

> Note: if your application is not listed, try just to switch back to your app.

[image]

---

That's it!
After the above commands, everything started to work as I would expect.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me, simply start the app from the expo app itself and it worked

Comment: I can't for the life of me get the menu to open with Disable Fast Refresh (etc) to appear. How did you do that within the Expo app on Android Simulator?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on that one currently. Did this a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but in my case, react-navigation header is the cause of this issue. Everytime i allow displaying header, ctrl+M doesn't work anymore. If you're using react-navigation with `headerShown: true`, try setting it to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

check your Expo DevTools in the browser and disable the production mode. i had the same issue and was banging my head with my keyboard for 5 long hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, if you are developing on Visual Studio Code, Windows, using expo, you can use the terminal where the app is running in VSC, and press just the m key and it will toggle the developer menu on the emulator. I believe the issue is something to do with the navigation as my problem also started once I adjusted some navigation components in the app.

Answer (score 0):

u just need to log in into expo account on android emulator